# In Play Framework, how and when are changes to models synchronized with the DB schema?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

In the Play Framework, when i add or modify a model, when is the update made to the database schema?  is this done automatically, or do i need to initiate it manually somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are running in Dev mode, then it is done immediately. The definition of immediately is when a server request is next invoked, the update check is made and this kicks off the process for recompiling your Java classes, and as a result the database schema also.

If it is in Prod mode, then it is when the server starts.